# How does freenode IRC assign the user string in their join address. I.e nick!user@host

Tags: irc

How is this set? When I see people joining a server their nick!user@host is something like:

```
640130f8@gateway/web/cgi-irc/kiwiirc.com/ip.100.1.48.248
```

The  `"640130f8"` Is the user field and it seems to not be randomly generated. As Ip's similar to that of the one present in that join information, also have a similar user  field. For instance:

```
5e9fbe84@gateway/web/cgi-irc/kiwiirc.com/ip.94.159.45.56

5e9fdbed@gateway/web/cgi-irc/kiwiirc.com/ip.94.159.214.24
```

So how is that generated?
I ask for the reason that I see channel operators banning using that in their bans and don't particularly understand why. They often use the first 4 letters of that string, which seems to be the consistent part of it. I'm not too sure how that works though.

Any help in explaining how this works is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That string (originally intended to be the operating system user) is passed from the IRC client itself. However, a lot of computers don't run the service (identd) necessary for the server to discover that information, and accept a client-customisable string sent as part of the connection registration. If this is the case, a tilde (~) is prepended to it by freenode.

In the case of KiwiIRC (and other web-based clients), Kiwi set that string to be a hexadecimal-encoded version of the user's IP address. Freenode doesn't assign it, KiwiIRC do.

In your example, 640130F8 becomes:

- Hexadecimal 64 = Decimal 100
- Hexadecimal 01 = Decimal 1
- Hexadecimal 30 = Decimal 48
- Hexadecimal F8 = Decimal 248